# How to obtain phpMyAdmin version from command line?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line, version, phpmyadmin

My question applies to Debian/Ubuntu:

Prior to updating/upgrading my Linux environment I want to implement best-practice procedures by taking a snapshot of my components' versions  through a simple script that records into a text file version numbers for OS, mySQL, PHP and so on.

However I can't find anywhere how to [reliably obtain version number](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=phpmyadmin%20version%20check) for [phpMyAdmin via command line](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=phpmyadmin%20version%20command%20line).

If there is no better way I'm happy to grep files such as

`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/Config.php` or `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/package.json` .

Am I missing something?

I know how to check version number via phpMyAdmin's web interface but that is not helpful for what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you’re also following the best practice of using packages,

```
dpkg -l phpmyadmin
```

will tell you which version of the `phpmyadmin` package is installed (assuming it is installed).

If you only want the version,

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${version}\n' phpmyadmin
```

will only output the version of `phpmyadmin`.

If you’re not using a packaged version, but you know where the `package.json` file lives,

```
jq .version /path/to/package.json
```

will give you the version.

If you want to query the version from the web server, you need to look for `PMA_VERSION` in the home page:

```
curl -s https://example.org/phpmyadmin | grep -E -o 'PMA_VERSION:"[[:digit:].]+"'
```

Comment: Stephen, I should have probably mentioned that one of the systems I have is a bare-bones GUI-less Debian installation, so packages such as `jq` are not available. However from the gist of your updated answer sounds like grepping the `package.json` is close enough to the `jq` method, which is good enough for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep-status` from `dctrl-tools` tool:

```
grep-status -sPackage,Version -PX 'phpmyadmin'
```

sample output:

```
Package: phpmyadmin
Version: 4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2
```

[grep-status manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dctrl-tools/grep-status.1.en.html)